# converting string into json object

Tags: java, json

I am getting a string like `String s = "abc:xyz"`. Is there any direct method to convert it into JsonObject having abc as key and xyz as value.

I know there a way by converting string into `String s = "{\"abc\":\"xyz\"}"` and then I can use `JSONObject j =(JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(s);` But I have too large list of string to convert into json object. So i don't want to preprocess to convert into quoted string.

And one more way to split string on : . But i want to know any parser method which convert directly into object. So that i does not have to split. It is also a kind of preprocessing.

If there is any way to convert by passing string to method. please suggest.

Comment: You might use a tool for "comma separated strings"/"comma delimited lists".  I'm thinking there's one called CDLtoJSON or something like that.  (You'd either tell it the separator is ":" or simply translate ":" to "," before processing.)

Comment: It's called "CDL.toJSONArray".  Have no idea where you get it.

Comment: Whatever method you would call will basically split; there isn't some magic to make this faster, and the code to use split is about as simple as one could hope for.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want:

```
String[] bits = s.split(":");
if (bits.length() != 2) {
    // Throw an exception or whatever you want
}
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put(bits[0], bits[1]);
```

Comment: actually, I don't want to preprocess it. Is there any direct method in Json simple api to parse such string

Comment: @kriyeta: No, because it's not json. If it were real JSON you could just parse it - but you've said you don't want to convert it into real JSON. This is a *tiny* amount of work - what problem does it cause if you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on :; use the parts to make your object.